# How to create an observable StackLayout with different types of controls in MAUI

Tags: c#, binding, maui

I'm trying to come up with a better way to create something similar to the ObservableCollection but of different types.
The goal is to have a way of adding new types of controls (labels and/or buttons) without needing to replace the current content with `Content = myNewLayout` etc.

I've looked at ObservableCollection but looks like it works best on elements of one type (e.g. `Label`) whereas I need to support multiple types.
Right now I'm considering replacing a content every time like so:

```cs
async void StartTurnButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var initialSteps = Turns.Take(2);

        StackLayout vsl = new StackLayout { Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical };
        foreach (var step in initialSteps)
        {
            Label label = new Label
            {
                Text = step.label,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };
            vsl.Add(label);
        }

        // Test
        vsl.Add(new Button { Text = "test" });

        // Last resort:
        Content = vsl;
    }
```

and it works as intended but it doesn't seem like the right way.

Is it possible to create something like observable stack layout and create a binding for the children in the XAML?

Comment: it's unclear to me exactly what you're trying to accomplish by this.  A `StackLayout` can already contain different types.